# error on date and time for discord with python

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!now')
    userID = message.author.id
    await client.send_message(message.channel, '<@&s>' (time.asctime() % '(userID)')
```

I'm getting syntax error
trying to make a command for discord bot when other type !now it will respond their date and time

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've copied the code correctly but it seems like you're missing:

- An underscore in the name of your function (`def on_message(message):`)
- A colon at the end of you `if` statement and the right indentation
  underneath ( `if message.content.upper().startswith('!now'):`)

As Mehvix pointed out you are also comparing a string that you've converted into uppercase to a string that is lowercase   ( switch to `if message.content.startswith('!now'):` )

I would also recommend using the newer formatting features of python to change the await line into something like this `await client.send_message(message.channel, f'{time.asctime()} -> {message.author.id}')`

This is the end result

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('!now'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, f'{time.asctime()} -> {message.author.id}')
```

Comment: perfect I got it running with no error but now when I type !now on discord nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

`.upper` means that "!now" needs to be capitalized to "!NOW"

Comment: thankyou fix this but I'm still facing a lot of error